# На что указывает arg в va_start?

Tags: c

Вот код. Комментарием пометил место, где возникает вопрос. Данный printf() выводит размер в 9 байт. Я не очень понимаю, как это работает.

```
char* add_to_string(const char *format, char *dest, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int user_str_size = sizeof(*dest) * strlen(dest);
    va_start(arg, dest);
    int new_size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, arg);
    printf("Size %d\n", new_size); // не понимаю вывод в этом месте!
    va_end(arg);
    dest = (char *)realloc(dest, sizeof(char) * new_size + 1);
    va_start(arg, dest);
    vsnprintf(dest + strlen(dest), new_size - user_str_size + 1, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return dest;
}
```

```
char *r = strdup("Aa ");
r = add_to_string("%s %s %s", r, "Bb", "Cc");
```

Вывод моей программы:
Size 9
Aa Bb Cc

Получается, что arg указывает на dest, а не на элементы после него, так?
Вот пример из интернета.

```
void PrintFError ( const char * format, ... )
{
  char buffer[256];
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vsnprintf (buffer,256,format, args);
  perror (buffer);
  va_end (args);
}

int main ()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char szFileName[]="myfile.txt";

   pFile = fopen (szFileName,"r");
   if (pFile == NULL)
     PrintFError ("Error opening '%s'",szFileName);
   else
   {
     // file successfully open
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Вывод их программы:
Error opening file 'myfile.txt': No such file or directory

Так вот у меня вопрос, на что указывает arg после va_start? Почему мой vsprintf возвращает 9, а не 6. Почему в программе из интернета их format не подставляется в строку результата.
Если бы их vsprintf работал бы так же, то они бы получили в результате строку "Error opening 'Error opening '%s''", потому что args указывает на формат. Проще говоря, я не понимаю, почему строка 'Aа ' в принципе учитывается в первом вызове vsprintf и первый вызов возращает мне 9,а не 6

Comment: `arg` никуда не указывает, это фиктивная переменная для доступа к списку параметров переменной длины. А программа содержит неопределенное поведение, так как количество аргументов в списке не соответствует паттерну при вызове vsnprintf (должно быть 3, а по факту только 2).

Comment: What is this va_list? It’s effectively a pointer to an arguments in the var-args array. After calling va_start, argp points at the first var-argument.
https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/23/c-varargs/

Comment: Вызов функции `vsnprintf(NULL, 0, ...)` ничего не пишет в буфер (вы же передали, что его размер 0), но вычисляет, сколько байт туда должно было быть записано и возвращает это число. Тут все верно -- 9 символов для передаваемых аргументов и печати по формату `"%s %s %s"`. Далее вы, вообще говоря, делаете неправильные вещи, выделяете память избыточного  размера поверх данных переданных для печати в первом `%s` в формате, но вам повезло (или нет,  я бы предпочел тут упасть, чтобы ошибка сразу стала очевидной) и вы получили вторым `vsnprintf()` правильные данные в выделенном буфере

Comment: @avp 
Стоп, не очень понимаю, почему все же 9, ведь аргументов всего  2. Как туда попадает переменная dest?

Comment: @avp
Ведь он не должен ее брать, она не является частью va_list

Comment: @avp 
Так все равно не понял. Почему 9? Когда в arg лежать должно лишь 2 переменные а третий спецификатор должен выдать либо еррор либо я не знаю что

Comment: @АндрейПетров, согласен, я ошибся в своем комментарии. Кстати, у меня (Linux, 64-bit) ваш код падает с segfault. В вашей функции несколько ошибок, а основная (для вызова `add_to_string("%s %s %s", r, "Bb", "Cc");`) это 3 %s в формате. Нужно 2. / Что касается непосредственно вопроса, **почему выводит 9?**, то мне кажется, что у вас 32-бит система и параметры передаются через стек. Похоже, что в этом случае vsnprintf, разбирая формат, для последнего %s получает адрес, который указывает на строку из 3-х ненулевых байт.

Comment: Правильный (насколько я понимаю задумку) вариант функции привожу в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

**`arg` в `va_start(arg, dest);` указывает на аргумент, следующий в списке вызова непосредственно за `dest`**.

У меня (Linux, 64-bit) поведение вашей программы (из-за ошибки -- лишний `%s` в формате `%s %s %s`) не воспроизводится.

Предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что у вас 32-бит ОС, параметры передаются через стек и в вашем случае лишний аргумент (который вы не передаете в `vsnprintf()`) адресует "удачно расположеный" мусор в памяти.

Насколько я понял задумку
(добавить к строке, передаваемой во втором аргументе, содержимое строк из 3-го и 4-го  аргументов)
правильный вариант функции должен быть вот таким:

```
char* add_to_string(const char *format, char *dest, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int user_str_size = strlen(dest);
    va_start(arg, dest);
    int new_size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, arg);
    printf("Size %d\n", new_size); // не понимаю вывод в этом месте!
    va_end(arg);

    dest = (char *)realloc(dest, user_str_size + new_size + 1);
    va_start(arg, dest);
    vsnprintf(dest + user_str_size, user_str_size + new_size, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return dest;
}
```

Естественно, при вызове строка формата должна содержать 2 `%s`

```
  char *r = strdup("Aa ");
  r = add_to_string("%s %s", r, "Bb", "Cc");

  printf("r = <%s>\n", r);
```

---